# Allowing Google to index images on s3

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt, amazon-s3

We host our sites' static content on S3. We also have a very open robots.txt;

```
User-agent: *
Allow: *
```

This is because in Webmaster tools I get thousands of warnings `Sitemap contains urls which are blocked by robots.txt.`

The images are listed in my sitemap along with a content item and use the correct path; http://mybucket.s3.amazon.com/image/path.jpg.

Can I add a remote URL in my robots.txt? I'm assuming, with such a liberal robots.txt on s3, that this is a restriction in my site's robots.txt.

Has anybody else stored images on s3 and put them in a sitemap?

Comment: You put a separate robots.txt on the S3.

Answer (score 1):

`Allow: *` should actually be be `Allow: /`.

That could be the issue... because, really, using `Allow:` is somewhat meaningless by itself -- its purpose is for allowing a sub-path within a denied path.  As it stands, it seems possible that your file is being misinterpreted.

Anything not denied is supposed to be implicitly allowed.

If you want to allow everything, you should instead use `Disallow:` with nothing after it... or of course you could just delete your `/robots.txt` file entirely, since a 4xx error should be interpreted by a crawler as "no restrictions here -- have fun!"

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the answer. We had no robots.txt originally and were getting these warnings in Webmaster Tools, so I added a robots as I assumed it was blocking by default. Can I add something in the local site robots to allow the remote file store?

Comment: Your use of the words "local" and "remote" makes me realize that I misread part of your question, actually... You said "we host our sites' static content" but I saw "we host our static site's content" ... I didn't realize the entire site wasn't a static site in S3 on a single domain name. So, yes, in that light, it sounds like this is not about S3 but about restrictions in the robots.txt file on the main site... which is not the brief one in the question. (right?)  Also, no, you can't provide rules for any other origin in robots.txt.

Comment: Ok, so, currently then there *should* be no reason why Google could not access our static content?

Comment: Well, no, I don't see why... not unless, as I pointed out initially, `Allow: *` is being misinterpreted.

Comment: I updated my robots.txt to / instead of * and while nothing has been indexed, all my warnings have disappeared. Fingers crossed.